# Check if fingerprint scanner is on screen

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fingerprint-api

Is there a way to check the place of the fingerprint scanner? Actually I just want to know if the fingerprint scanner is on the screen. I've tried to check the methods on the existing android fingerprint API but it seems that there's no method for that.

I'm asking this just for the sake of UI, some devices covers part of the screen with a fingerprint icon (where the scanner is) so we can adjust the UI if it is on screen.